# I want to disable correct hyperlink

Tags: jquery

This is my last question diabling a hyperlink. The hyperlink does disable but the problem is that is disabling all hyperlinks with the same class. All hyperlinks have the same class, if not then they won't work. But I only want the hyperlink on top (in html) to be only disabled not the hyperlinks in the added rows (jquery code) to be disabled. How can I differenciate the 2 so that not all hyperlinks are disabled?

Below is code for disabling the hyperlink:

```
 $(".showGrid").unbind('click').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    })
```

Below is hyperlink in full html (I want this hyperlink to be disabled):

```
<table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">
<tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        Option and Answer
    </th>
</tr>
<tr class="option">
<td>Option Type:</td>
<td>
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="gridValues" class="gridTxt maxRow" readonly="readonly" />
    <a href="#" class="showGrid">[Open Grid]</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Below is hyperlink in jquery code (Don't Disable this hyperlink):

```
function insertQuestion(form) {  

var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
 var $options = $("<td class='option'></td>");

  $('.gridTxt', context).each( function() {

     var $this = $(this);
     var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' /><span href='#' class='showGrid'>[Open Grid]</span>").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                     .attr('value',$this.val())

    $options.append($optionsText);

    });

$tr.append($options);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add a id and disable by using $("#new_id")?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a number of things with jQuery selectors...

`$(".box a")` would select all anchor tags that are descendants of elements with the 'box' class

You could add an Id to your anchor tag, and grab it that way. This is the most efficient..

```
<a id="openGridLink" href="#">[Open Grid]</a>

$("#openGridLink")
```

would select that (note that Ids must be unique on a page)

Look here for more selector options

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

If all you're worried about is making sure that only your static HTML gets the `click` handler and not the dynamically added ones, then just add the `click` handler **before** adding the new links.

```
// jQuery 1.7.x
$(".showGrid").off('click').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // return false;   <-- you PROBABLY don't need this anymore.
});

// add the new links here
```

If you can't do that, then select by position.

```
$("tr.option:first-child .showGrid").off('click').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you *also* can't do that, then I'd suggest adding a new class to your dynamic links.

```
var $optionsText = 
    $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' /><span href='#' class='showGrid dynamic'>[Open Grid]</span>")
        .attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
        .attr('value', $this.val());

// then modify your event hook like this:
$(".showGrid:not(.dynamic)").off("click").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Using a class over an ID is not only more semantic, but you won't have to worry about name collisions when auto-generating multiple IDs.